# How to Test login as Facebook in the web?

Tags: facebook, selenium-webdriver

I have web site to test and there is login option as "Sign in With Facebook."

While doing that my Facebook account got blocked due to continuously login in with Facebook.

Sometimes, it asked OTP for security check.

Which approach will work to do the test of Login as Facebook? What is your feedback on this?

[Facebook Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLWco.png)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

Comment: Thanks @CBroe Thanks for the update. I tried and displayed pop up with the error saying that developers need to configure those test user. I will update you once it is done.  I will request to the developer to give access.